# Como cambiar color de los ejes de un grafico en c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

Quiero cambiar el color de los números de los ejes x e y. Abajo puse una imagen encerrando en amarillo lo que quiero cambiar de color. Puedo modificarlo desde la barra de propiedades? u otra forma?.. Esto es en Windows Forms.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que edite tu pregunta añadiendo el código con el que generas el gráfico y lo que has intentado, saludos

Comment: web? winforms? wpf? uwp?

Comment: WinForms estimado

Comment: chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red; y chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Comment: Gracias @LuisGutierrez me sirvio tu respuesta. Si quieres la dejas como respuesta a mi pregunta para marcarla y cerrar el hilo.

Comment: Hola JaviYeri, que bueno que te funcionó, puedes marcar al lado de mi respuesta el check verde para marcarlo como la respuesta correcta. Al menos creo que es asi... Saludos.